# Walrus operator, multiple assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following `while` loop:

```
import re
line = "This is my line"
reg = re.compile('(\S+)\s*(.*)')
while line:
    token, line = reg.match(line).groups()
    print (token)
```

Is it possible to put this into a walrus-operator expression? It seems [not natively](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements), but I was wondering if it could be done in some sort of hack-ish way, perhaps with multiple `:=`'s. Ideally, this is what it would be:

```
while (token, line := reg.match(line).groups()):
    print (token)
```

Is that possible to do at all?

Comment: No,  The problem is that walrus cannot be used to assign to a tuple.  So, this would be a syntax error.  Even if it could, you would need the target of the `while` statement to be `line`, (to match `while line:`) and there would be no way to specify that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the closest thing you can do is something like this:

```py
while r := reg.match(line).groups() and (token := r[0], line := r[1]) and line:
    print(token)
```

But why would you do this? It is bad code. Don't do this. The original code in your question is better.

That said, it looks like your tokens are groups of non-whitespace characters, delimited by whitespace - note that even though `\s*` can possibly match no whitespace, this only happens at the end of the input, because `\S+` greedily matches as many non-whitespace characters as it can. If this is indeed what you are trying to do, then you should just write this:

```py
for token in line.split():
    print(token)
```

Or if you insist on using a regex, you should just write this:

```py
reg = re.compile(r'\S+')

for token in reg.findall(line):
    print(token)
```